# Command is not found using `ssh root@host command`

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

Assume there are host A and host B and A can ssh B without password.

When I run `ssh root@B ls` from A's shell, the `ls` is executed and output is showing.

However, when I run something like `ssh root@B yarn` from A's shell, `bash: yarn: command not found` is showing.

I'm sure that `yarn` is available by manually input `yarn` at B's shell.

I guess it's about permission issue. `ls` and `yarn` may have different execution level.

So what's the exact reason of it and how can I make `ssh root@B yarn` available from A's shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `yarn` command is in some non-standard location that was added to $PATH through the shell's initialization scripts (e.g. ~/.bashrc or ~/.*profile or /etc/profile.d).

The problem is that Bash often completely ignores these scripts when being run in non-interactive mode. If you compare `printenv PATH` entered interactively with `ssh root@B printenv PATH` started non-interactively, you'll probably see different values.

Fixing this depends on the remote server's OS:

- `ssh root@B ". /etc/profile && yarn ..."` should always work (assuming /etc/profile is where PATH is getting set; you'll need to replace it with the correct filename otherwise).
- Linking the `yarn` command to one of the standard $PATH locations (e.g. /usr/bin or often /usr/local/bin) should always work – assuming it doesn't require *other* environment variables to be present.
- Creating a shellscript at `/usr/[local/]bin/yarn` which sets all required environment variables and runs the real thing should always work.
- Setting $PATH through ~/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc will work on Debian/Ubuntu, but won't work on most other distributions (unfortunately Bash offers this as a compile-time option).
- Setting $PATH through ~/.pam_environment or /etc/environment will work on some distributions. Note that these are not shell scripts and use a different syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explanation and I fixed issue by your forth bullet, 'setting $PATH through ~/.bashrc`.